# Rails what is the difference between content_for and yield?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example:  `content_for(:stuff)` vs `yield :stuff`

I know they are implemented slightly differently, but is there any real functionality difference?

Is there a generally accepted best practice?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

`yield` is how you specify where your content areas is going to go within a layout. You might have something like this:

```
<div>
  <h1> This is the wrapper!</h1>
  <%= yield :my_content %>
</div>
```

`content_for` is how you specify which content is going to be rendered into which content area. You might have something like this:

```
<% content_for :my_content do %>
  This is the content.
<% end %>
```

The result would be

```
<div>
  <h1> This is the wrapper!</h1>
  This is the content.
</div>
```

They are opposite ends of the rendering process, with `yield` specifying where content goes, and `content_for` specifying what the actual content *is*.

> Is there a generally accepted best practice?

The best practice is to use `yield` in your layouts, and `content_for` in your views. There is a special second use for `content_for`, where you give it no block and it returns the previously rendered content. This is primarily for use in helper methods where `yield` cannot work. Within your views, the best practice is to stick to `yield :my_content` to recall the content, and `content_for :my_content do...end` to render the content.

Answer (score 3):

yield:

> yield identifies a section where content from the view should be
>   inserted

content_for:

> The content_for method allows you to insert content into a named yield
>   block in your layout. For example, this view would work with the
>   layout that you just saw:

`yield :stuff` will grab the contents that are pushed by `content_for(:stuff)`

So, using `yield` you can define the sections in your view/layouts and you use `content_for` for adding contents to those sections. Any unnamed `yield` will grab all other contents.

You can learn more about it reading the [tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield).

Comment: But wait, this also works for me, in the model view, I have content_for :stuff, "the stuff"  and in the layout view I have if content_for?(:stuff) content_for(:stuff) ... bypassing the need for 'yield'...

Comment: this does not make any sense. it should be like `if content_for?(:stuff) yield(:stuff)`. It means that, if `:stuff` has something to yield/produce, you produce it. This is needed when your parent will render something different based on the yield

Comment: No, if `content_for` is invoked with no block, it returns the previously rendered content, if any.

Answer (score 2):

Calling #content_for stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. In order to access this stored content in other templates, helper modules or the layout, you would pass the identifier as an argument to content_for.
yield can still be used to retrieve the stored content, but calling yield doesn't work in helper modules, while content_for does....more: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for

Answer (score 2):

From the Ruby on Rails API:

> Calling `content_for` stores a block of markup in an identifier for later use. In order to access this stored content in other templates, helper modules or the layout, you would pass the identifier as an argument to `content_for`.
>
> Note: `yield` can still be used to retrieve the stored content, but calling `yield` doesn't work in helper modules, while `content_for` does.
>
> You can then use `content_for :not_authorized` anywhere in your templates.

```
<%= content_for :not_authorized if current_user.nil? %>
```

> This is equivalent to:

```
<%= yield :not_authorized if current_user.nil? %>
```

> `content_for`, however, can also be used in helper modules.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CaptureHelper.html#method-i-content_for