# Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check <% content_for :show do %> <div class="container"> <h1 style="color: aliceblue">

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

i am new to RoR and still learning, can anyone explain me how and where to use the `<%= yield :whatever %>` in the **layouts/application.html.erb**,

i tried yield with **index.html.erb** by using `<% content_for :header do %>` and placed `<%= yield :header %>` in the **layouts/application.html.erb**
and it was working perfectly fine.

now when i try it with **show.html.erb** by using `<% content_for :show do %>` and placed `<%= yield :show %>` in the **layouts/application.html.erb**, its still working fine, but when i try to add other elements using `<ul>, <li>, <% %>, <%= %>`, it shows me the error

Encountered a syntax error while rendering template: check

```
<% content_for :show do %>
  

    <div class="container">
        <h1 style="color: aliceblue">
          <%= @instrument.title %>...............
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flinger</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
    <%= javascript_importmap_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="conatiner-fluid" style="
    background: #1f4037;  /* fallback for old browsers */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #99f2c8, #1f4037);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #99f2c8, #1f4037);">
      <%= render 'layouts/nav'%>
      <%= yield :header %>
      <%= yield :show%>
    </div>

    <div class="container">  
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

index.html.erb

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="color: aliceblue">
      Browse the latest instruments on Flinger
    </h1>
  </div>
<% end %>


<div class="container">
  <div class="card" style="width: fit-content;">
    <% @instruments.each do |instrument| %>
      
      <%= link_to image_tag(instrument.image_url(:thumb)), instrument, class: "card-img-top" %>
    
      <% if instrument.condition? %>
        <p class="list-group list-group-flush"><%= instrument.condition %></p> 
      <% end %>

      
      <h3 class="list-group-item"><%= link_to instrument.title, instrument %></h3>

      <p class="list-group-item">Sold by <%= instrument.user.name %></p>

      <p class="list-group-item"><%= number_to_currency(instrument.price) %></p>

      <% if instrument_author(instrument) %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_instrument_path(instrument), class:"btn btn-info ediit-butt" %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', instrument, method: :delete, class:"btn btn-danger deel-butt" %>
      <% end %>

    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

show.html.erb

```
<% content_for :show do %>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 style="color: aliceblue">
      <%= @instrument.title %>
    </h1>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div class="conatainer">
  <% @instruments.each do | instrument | %>
    <ul>
      <%= if instrument.brand? %>
        <li><%= instrument.brand %></li>     
      <% end %>

      <%= if instrument.model %>
        <li><%= instrument.model %></li>     
      <% end %>

      <%= if instrument.condition %>
        <li><%= instrument.condition %></li>     
      <% end %>

      <%= if instrument.finish %>
        <li><%= instrument.finish %></li>     
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

UPDATE: it was my mistake that i used `<%= %>` for if condition instead of `<% %>` and also in my **instruments_controller.rb** , there was a global variable `@instruments = Instrument.all.order("created_at desc")` in the **index method**, but whereas in **show method**, there wasn't anything, so the problem was i used the same global variable of **index method** in the **show.html.erb** whereas i had a different variable to use for all view files

Comment: " but when i try to add other elements using <ul>, <li>, <% %>, <%= %>, it shows me the error"  Where are you trying to add these elements?  Given that you yield for both header and show right after one another, do you really need both?

Comment: i am trying to display those elements on the page show.html.erb, as i said that i am a beginner and still learning, according to the knowledge what i have is when i put <%= yield :show %> on application.html.erb , it brings the content from content_for :show from show.html.erb page whenever someone visits the show page

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/13151073/1880203

Comment: No way this is related with rails 3 and 4, so removing the tags

Comment: @uma, I believe that you understand the use of "yield <something>" correctly 00 you essentially create an optional placeholder for content.  I am asking a slightly different question.  You have created two such placeholders in the same space -- there is no content that distinguishes them.  Because of that, it looks like you could use just one placeholder.

When you said that you got a syntax error "when I try to add other elements", where are you trying to add those other elements?  Are they in the content_for block in your show page?  Somewhere in the main application layout?